# MYSQL неправильный парсинг в порядке убывания

Tags: php, mysql, redbeanphp

Эти кодом парсю елементы постов из

```
$all = R::findAll('postdate'," ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15");
    for($i = 1; $i <= count($all); $i++){
        if(isset($all[$i])){
            $date = date_create($all[$i]->date);
            $post = R::findOne('post', 'date_id = ?', array($all[$i]->id));
            $author = R::findOne('postauthor', 'id = ?', array($post->author_id));
            $title = R::findOne('posttitle', 'id = ?', array($post->title_id));
            echo '<div class=post>
                      <i class=post-date>'.date_format($date, 'd.m.Y G:i').'  '.$author->author.'</i>
                      <h1>'.$title->title.'</h1><hr><br>'.
                      $post->content.
                  '</div>';
        }
        
    }
```

но в итоге последние посты не находятся и всё идет в порядке возрастания. Помогите, пожалуйста. Через дату тоже пробовал

EDIT: Это проблема stackoverflow. Я и использую
$all = R::findAll('postdate'," ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 25");
но эта часть кода исчезла

Answer (score 0):

```
        $all = R::getAll( 'SELECT * FROM postdate ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 125' );
        for($i = -1; $i <= count($all); $i++){
            if(isset($all[$i])){
                $date = date_create($all[$i]['date']);
                $post = R::findOne('post', 'date_id = ?', array($all[$i]['id']));
                $author = R::findOne('postauthor', 'id = ?', array($post->author_id));
                $title = R::findOne('posttitle', 'id = ?', array($post->title_id));
                echo '<div class=post>
                          <i class=post-date>'.date_format($date, 'd.m.Y G:i').'  '.$author->author.'</i>
                          <h1>'.$title->title.'</h1><hr><br>'.
                          $post->content.
                      '</div>';
            }
        }
```